# Spark not writing to Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a Spark application that was writing to Hive partitioned table perfectly. I added two new columns in the Dataframe that I was persisting in Hive and it stopped writing to Hive and silently didn't insert any rows.

I have a `DF3 = DF1.join(DF2, where(...), "inner")`. I am persisting DF3. The log output of the join is showing up, no error log.

1. In DF3 will all the columns of DF1 and DF2 automatically come?
2. I added 2 new cols which I am getting from DF2 in the Hive schema too and the order is maintained between code and Hive schema (i.e just after the last col at both places). Any thoughts why its not writing into hive?

Comment: Have you described your dataframe and your hive table and compared them?

Comment: Yes, they look ok. Is this join correct ? Looks like it is hanging here : DataFrame DFJoin = DF1.join(DF2, DF1.col("device").equalTo(DF2.col("id")).or(DF1.col("device").equalTo(DF2.col("new_id"))), "inner");

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the hive metadata by using any of the following

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE
REFRESH [db_name.]table_name
INVALIDATE METADATA [table_name]
```